# Showing ios app store comments from different country

Tags: ios-appstore

I would like to see the comments from other countries (ie. us) while leaving my appstore set to my country (Hungary) for updates. Unfortunately, there are few comments written here for apps, most of the time there are none, which isn't too helpful.

Is there any way to do this? I have only a hungarian credit card. I can show comments by switching to US, but I cannot update apps until I switch back. Switching only for buying would be acceptable if there is no alternative.

Thanks!

Edit: from my ipad, without using my computer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a "main" webpage to browse from directly, but if you do search for the name of an app and then "itunes.apple.com" or "Mac App Store" you will get to visit the app's page in your browser.

Take Reeder for example:

- [Mac](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reeder/id439845554?mt=12)
- [iPhone/iPod](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reeder/id325502379?mt=8)
- [iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reeder-for-ipad/id375661689?mt=8)

You can change the country by using the country flag on the bottom right of the page, or directly on the URL if you know the country code.

Comment: Edited my original question, I would like to do this from my ipad, it opens its app with my country for the ipad/iphone links, and some mac appstore thing for the first which shows only Learn more